# Возврат в исходное положение при клике на стороннюю область

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! Есть два блока - второй появляется при клике на первый и должен исчезать при клике на любую область кроме своей собственное.

Мой скрипт работает некорректно - выпадающий блок появляется и сразу исчезает... Я понимаю, что должна быть определенная последовательность, т.к. обе функции выполняются одновременно, но как её задать не знаю. Просьба помочь

Плюс мне не понятно, почему при клике на блок `.header` появляющийся блок как-бы моргает. По идее он должен получить `opacity: 1`, а потом его значение сразу должно измениться на `opacity: 0`

```js
$(function() {
  var searchformBlock = $('.menu');

  $('body').click(function() {
    if ($(searchformBlock).hasClass('active')) {
      $(searchformBlock).fadeOut().removeClass('active');
    }
  })

  $('.header').click(function () {
    $(searchformBlock).toggleClass('active');

    if ($(searchformBlock).hasClass('active')) {
      $(searchformBlock).fadeIn();
    } else {
      $(searchformBlock).fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fecf5e, #ffcc50);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fecf5e, #ffcc50);
  z-index: 101;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background: #a7a7a7;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.header').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
  var handler;
  
  if (menu.hidden) {
    menu.hidden = false;
    
    menu.addEventListener('click', handler = function (event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }, true);
    
    document.addEventListener('click', function hide(event) {
      menu.hidden = true;
      menu.removeEventListener('click', handler, true);
      document.removeEventListener('click', hide, true);
    }, true);
  }
})
```

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fecf5e, #ffcc50);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fecf5e, #ffcc50);
  z-index: 101;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background: #a7a7a7;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 100;
  
  animation: opacity-0-to-1 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}

@keyframes opacity-0-to-1 {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="menu" hidden="hidden"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваше событие - клик по `.header` всплывает до `body`, из-за чего блок тут же скрывает. Предотвращаем всплытие с помощью `e.stopPropagation`

```js
$(function() {
  var searchformBlock = $('.menu');

  $('body').click(function() {
    if (searchformBlock.hasClass('active')) {
      searchformBlock.fadeOut().removeClass('active');
    }
  })

  $('.header').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    searchformBlock.toggleClass('active');

    if (searchformBlock.hasClass('active')) {
      searchformBlock.fadeIn();
    } else {
      searchformBlock.fadeOut();
    }
  });

  searchformBlock.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fecf5e, #ffcc50);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fecf5e, #ffcc50);
  z-index: 101;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background: #a7a7a7;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Comment: Ваш вариант не работает. Задача у автора убирать выпадающий блок, если кликнули куда угодно.

Comment: Если вы про то, что блок не закрывается по клику на белую область - то там ничего нет, все элементы абсолютно спозиционированы  и высота у `body` 0 пикселей. В реальности такого не будет.